# passive voice sentence begins with wh- word

Tags: passive-voice, wh-questions

I am confused about a wh-- question.

> who would you have me be loyal to?

I want to know what kind of sentence is this? A passive voice or a passive wh-- question?

what is the purpose of 'have' and 'be' in this sentence?

is "have" the auxiliary verb here or "be"?

if this is a passive voice what will be the active form of this sentence?

Comment: I think it's a question sentence. And the main verb here is "have". But it's a causative verb. So you can understand the meaning superficially like that: "which person would you make me loyal to".

Comment: _Have me be loyal_ here means _wish me to be loyal_. It is not passive voice.

Comment: @grammerian your nickname made my day, I laughed out loud!

Comment: Why? Am I wrong?

Comment: @grammerian it's very funny if it's a deliberate joke, or I am simply unaware of this alternative spelling

Comment: :))) Just for fun. But I like grammar. It's like the math of the language. It enables certainty and common ground in communication :) Otherwise, anyone could have used the language as he pleased :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Who would you have me be loyal to?

means

> In your opinion, who should I be loyal to?

or

> Who do you think I should be loyal to?

It's not passive. "to have somebody do something" (or "be something" in this case) means to convince them to do something or to arrange for them to do something.

Comment: Thank you, clearly explained.